# How to reject filter for a measure in Power Bi

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have a measure average example that gathers the average of all values.

```
Average = 
AVERAGEX (
VALUES ( Table[ID]),
CALCULATE ( COUNTX(SUMMARIZE(TABLE,TABLE[ID],TABLE[ID2]),
TABLE[ID2])
))
```

I am satisfied with the result but what I would like is to block the measure from being filtered completely. I want a stagnant result but that updates as I add more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ALL() to your calculate as a filter.

```
CALCULATE ( AverageX(....), All())
```